# Swift NSTextField Dictionary Gesture Interactions Disabling

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Trying to disabled this from happening, three finger trackpad gesture triggers this on a NSTextField

Attempted but appears not to do the trick.

```
   testing.refusesFirstResponder = true
```

[image]

Comment: How are you doing three finger trackpad gesture in an iPhone?

Comment: @PGDev why would this question be about iPhones? The screenshot clearly shows that this is about `macOS`.

Comment: Right, didn't even realise the `UI` prefix, edited the question for clarification

Comment: I think then the question is unclear. Also the relevant tags are also not provided.

Comment: See [How can I override the 3-finger tap behavior in a NSTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20618984/4244136) and do nothing in the override.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks, worked a charm. Others sorry about the confusion.