# macOS extend Force Touch look up popup

Tags: macos, trackpad, dictionary

I just want to add some functionality to “look up pop-up” (the pop-up when you force click) (check this: support.apple.com/kb/PH25145?locale=en_US). I looked for Apple documents and googled but couldn’t come across anything.

These were mainly links I found:

- [how to disable LookUp (Dictionary, Thesaurus, Wikipedia) functionality within a NSTextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830438/how-to-disable-lookup-dictionary-thesaurus-wikipedia-functionality-within-a)
- http://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html
- [How can I override the 3-finger tap behavior in a NSTextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507457/how-can-i-override-the-3-finger-tap-behavior-in-a-nstextview/20618984#20618984)
- http://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

In a nutshell, this (support.apple.com/kb/PH25145?locale=en_US) lookup popup is an interface apple provides with macos. Either force click or three fingers top, you can easily find something about the words, like meaning of the word, apps in appstore etc.. What I want is extend this lookup pop-up and add one more tab at the bottom. For example results from google for choosen words..

Actually, I am a web developer and to do this there is no problem for me to learn/use enough Swift, Objective-C, AppleScript, Python etc for coding.

What I mean is this popup. I just want to add for example one more tab to bottom of this pane:

[image: Lookup Popup]

Comment: i edited the question. i hope it is more clear now..

Comment: sorry for missplacement. thank you for your moderation.

Comment: This is an old question maybe but here are what I have found for implementing dictionaries:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/dictionary_services/
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/access/access.html

I have not seen a way to extend the look up view in other ways.